# how to access powershell session from another powershell window?

Tags: powershell

I have an powershell session created by

```
New-PSSession -ComputerName localhost
```

I'm able to access the above session by

```
PS C:\> Get-PSSession

 Id Name            ComputerName    State    ConfigurationName     Availability
 -- ----            ------------    -----    -----------------     ------------
  1 Session1        localhost       Opened   Microsoft.PowerShell     Available

PS C:\> Enter-PSSession -Id 1
```

Now if I open another powershell window, then can I access the session created above ?
I did try but "Enter-PSSession -Id 1" did't work for me. Is this possible at all ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot connect to sessions created in one instance from another one, sessions are isolated and available only to the host that created them.

Answer (score 0):

The [Enter-PSHostProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enter-pshostprocess) cmdlet connects to and enters into an interactive session with a local process. Beginning in PowerShell 6.2, this cmdlet is supported on non-Windows platforms.

To get the other session(s), you can use [$PID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#pid) or [Get-PSHostProcessInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-pshostprocessinfo).

```
PS C:\>Get-PSHostProcessInfo
    
ProcessName ProcessId AppDomainName    MainWindowTitle
----------- --------- -------------    ---------------
powershell      17148 DefaultAppDomain
powershell      25172 DefaultAppDomain
powershell      72348 DefaultAppDomain
pwsh            70732 DefaultAppDomain
pwsh            35072 DefaultAppDomain
pwsh            46624 DefaultAppDomain
pwsh            73228 DefaultAppDomain
```

Then you can connect to it using [Enter-PSHostProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enter-pshostprocess).

```
PS C:\>(Get-Process).Where({ $_.ID -eq 70732 }) | Get-PSHostProcessInfo | Enter-PSHostProcess
[Process:70732]: PS C:\Users\username\Documents> Get-Runspace
    
 Id Name            ComputerName    Type          State         Availability
 -- ----            ------------    ----          -----         ------------
  1 Runspace1       localhost       Local         Opened        Busy
  3 Runspace3       localhost       Local         Opened        Available
  4 Runspace4       localhost       Local         Opened        Available
  5 RemoteHost      localhost       Local         Opened        Busy
```

See [Enable-RunspaceDebug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/enable-runspacedebug) and [Debug-Runspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/debug-runspace) on debugging a Runspace from the session you connected to.